# sharing object protocol

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

I would like to know if someone has some idea or feedback about sharing data between thread or processes ( through a shared memory segment ). I was thinking about passing across the threads/process some ownership object ( through a pipe/ synchronized queue ). The only thread that can access data are the one owning the ownership of that object( or memory area ). If one thread wants to access an object that is own elsewhere then it gets an exception or it blocks . Any idea how to cleanly implement this protocol ?

Comment: This is not nearly enough to go on. What's the OS? The language? The runtime environment? The throughput requirements?

Comment: you can take C as language ( even if i dont target any specific OS/language ). I think that this could be transparent to these choices even if you are right there might be some specifics that may speed up things. I should maybe have used Pattern instead of Protocol.

Answer (score 1):

If you can extend your possible languages to include C++, [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/interprocess.html) supports portable shared memory.

You should be able to implement the blocking you describe by combining this with [condition variable in Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref).

Comment: Yes sounds like a very good starting point indeed. Are you aware of any documents/software describing this kind of behaviour ( actually i got the idea looking at a video from MSFT about their next OS generation called singularity )